# What is the groovy script to return contents of file?

Tags: groovy

I want to return the values of file in the return statement using groovy ?

ex: file has three lines abc,abd,abe then i should get output as return['abc','abd','abe']

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want to read the file contents into a list of Strings, with one list item for each line. The following will accomplish that:

```
List<String> fileContents = new File('/path/to/file.txt').readLines()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it gives me result [abc,abd,abe]
but i'm expecting "return['abc','abd','abe']" the word return needs to be present in the output and single quotes ('). Could you please provide me the same ?

Comment: @SurendraKumarGP `String result = "return ['${fileContents.join("', '")}']"`   But what happens if one of your lines contains a `'`?  Not sure what you're doing, but it doesn't sound 100% right